# Numba: how to speed up numerical simulation requiring also GUI

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, numba

I was just starting to learn about Numba to speed up for loops.
I've read it is [impossible to call a non-jitted function from a numba jitted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020389/calling-a-non-jitted-function-from-a-numba-jitted-function). Therefore I don't think I can `@jitclass(spec)` my class or `@njit` the main algorithm function (`compute()`)  leaving my code how it is, since every step of the simulation (`onestep()`) also changes the value of the pixel in the image `tkinter.Photoimage`, which is a Python type. So, I was wondering whether:

- there is any possible logical change to the program which would separate GUI and numerical part enough to allow Numba to be applied;
- there is any alternative to Tkinter compatible with Numba;
- there is any alternative to Numba which I may benefit from.

Here is a simplified version of my code for now:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
canv_w= 480
square_w = 16 #size of one element of the matrix
canvas=tk.Canvas(window,width=480,height=480)
canvas.pack()
my_image=tk.PhotoImage(width=480,height=480)
canvas.create_image((3, 3),image=my_image,anchor="nw",state="normal")
running =0

def pixel(self, i,j):

        if self.matrix[i,j]==-1:
            temp="#cc0000" #red
        elif self.matrix[i,j]==0:
            temp= "#fffafa" #white
        elif self.matrix[i,j]==1:
            temp="#7CFC00" #green
        my_image.put(temp,to=(i*square_w,j*square_w,(i+1)*square_w,(j+1)*square_w))

class myClass:

   def __init__(self, size):
        self.L=size
        self.matrix=np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], (self.L,self.L), p=[0.45,0.1,0.45])
        self.white_number=len(np.where(self.matrix==0)[0])
        self.iteration=0

        for i in range(self.L):
            for j in range(self.L):
                pixel(self,i,j)

   def onestep(self): 
        whites=np.where(self.matrix==0)# find position of all white squares
        my_v= np.random.choice(self.white_number)# randomly pick one white square...
        x=whites[0][my_v]
        y=whites[1][my_v]

        num= np.random.choice([0,1,2,3]) #...randomly pick one of its 4 neighbours
        neighbour=[[(x + 1)% self.L, y], [x, (y + 1) % self.L], [(x -  1)% self.L, y], [x, (y - 1)% self.L]]

        #swap with neighbour
        self.matrix[x,y]=self.matrix[neighbour[num][0],neighbour[num][1]]
        self.matrix[neighbour[num][0],neighbour[num][1]]=0

        pixel(self,x,y) #update the pixel the white square has left
        pixel(self,neighbour[num][0],neighbour[num][1]) #update the pixel the white atom has jumped to


   def compute(self):
    if running:
        for j in range(1, self.white_number + 1):
            self.onestep()

        self.iteration+=1

    window.after(1000,self.compute)



running=1

myObj=myClass(30)
myObj.compute()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

- there is any alternative to Numba which I may benefit from.

[cython](https://cython.org/) exists, and is more mature than numba, but it requires a compiler, so you only make compiled binaries, not JIT the functions, it provides static typing and it removes the interpreter overhead.

- there is any possible logical change to the program which would separate GUI and numerical part enough to allow Numba to be applied

you actually can call a non-jitted function using numba [objmode](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/withobjmode.html), but it still has some constraints, instead consider spliting each jitted function into a jitable part and a non-jitable part as shown

```py
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import numba

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
canv_w = 480
square_w = 16  # size of one element of the matrix
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=480, height=480)
canvas.pack()
my_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=480, height=480)
canvas.create_image((3, 3), image=my_image, anchor="nw", state="normal")
running = 0

def pixel(matrix, i, j):
    if matrix[i, j] == -1:
        temp = "#cc0000"  # red
    elif matrix[i, j] == 0:
        temp = "#fffafa"  # white
    elif matrix[i, j] == 1:
        temp = "#7CFC00"  # green
    my_image.put(temp, to=(i * square_w, j * square_w, (i + 1) * square_w, (j + 1) * square_w))

@numba.njit
def _onestep(matrix, white_number, L):
    whites = np.where(matrix == 0)  # find position of all white squares
    my_v = np.random.choice(white_number)  # randomly pick one white square...
    x = whites[0][my_v]
    y = whites[1][my_v]

    num = np.random.choice(np.array((0, 1, 2, 3)))  # ...randomly pick one of its 4 neighbours
    neighbour = [[(x + 1) % L, y], [x, (y + 1) % L], [(x - 1) % L, y], [x, (y - 1) % L]]

    # swap with neighbour
    matrix[x, y] = matrix[neighbour[num][0], neighbour[num][1]]
    matrix[neighbour[num][0], neighbour[num][1]] = 0
    return x,y,neighbour[num][0],neighbour[num][1]



class myClass:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.L = size
        self.matrix = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], (self.L, self.L), p=[0.45, 0.1, 0.45])
        self.white_number = len(np.where(self.matrix == 0)[0])
        self.iteration = 0

        for i in range(self.L):
            for j in range(self.L):
                pixel(self.matrix, i, j)

    def onestep(self):
        x,y,z1,z2 = _onestep(self.matrix, self.white_number, self.L)
        pixel(self.matrix, x, y)  # update the pixel the white square has left
        pixel(self.matrix, z1, z2)  # update the pixel the white atom has jumped to

    def compute(self):
        if running:
            for j in range(1, self.white_number + 1):
                self.onestep()

            self.iteration += 1

        window.after(1000, self.compute)


running = 1

myObj = myClass(30)
myObj.compute()

window.mainloop()
```

here `onestep` is not jitted, while `_onestep` that does the heavy-lifting is jitted.

there is some speedup (11 msec with numba vs 19 msec without numba per frame) in your program because most of the time is spent drawing, not in computation, so it won't benefit from any more "compiling".

the better approach would be to store all your screen data as 2d array and manipulate it in numba then redraw your entire screen in python at once instead of part by part.

cython would probably be able to get more optimized code out of this as it can mix python and non-python objects in the same function and remove the loop overhead, but writing code for it is harder than numba.